# Why does ActionView's "select_tag" escape the HTML in its "options" argument when called directly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeview

So I've been going through the very poor documentation that exists for ActionView, particularly a method called `select_tag` that just exists when called from view files. Supposedly, it's called like this:

```
select_tag name, option_tags, options
```

The [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) says nothing at all about the `name`, very little about the `options`, and describes the `option_tags` only through examples that treat it as an opaque value that must be obtained from other functions.

As always, the only way to learn anything about Rails is to reverse-engineer it.

So I tried running it directly from a Rails console, which is tricky because Ruby doesn't let you call methods that are defined in modules unless you create a class and an object first:

```
class H
  include ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper
end

H.new.options_for_select ["foo","bar"]
```

The above usage of `options_for_select` comes from actual code that somebody else wrote. The return value is a string:

```
"<option value=\"foo\">foo</option>\n<option value=\"bar\">bar</option>"
```

So apparently, you're supposed to pass the return value from `option_for_select` (or one of the many other related functions that introduce complications I don't want to talk about such as generating HTML tags from ActiveRecord objects) as the `option_tag` parameter of `select_tag`. Except if you copy that string to your clipboard and paste it directly into a function call, it doesn't do what you'd expect:

```
H.new.select_tag :my_name, "<option value=\"foo\">foo</option>\n<option value=\"bar\">bar</option>"
```

Return value:

```
"<select name=\"my_name\" id=\"my_name\">&lt;option value=&quot;foo&quot;&gt;foo&lt;/option&gt;\n&lt;option value=&quot;bar&quot;&gt;bar&lt;/option&gt;</select>"
```

At least this reveals what the `name` parameter is for.

Even weirder, the text is not escaped if you pass the return value *directly* to `select_tag` without letting it print on the console:

```
H.new.select_tag :name, H.new.options_for_select(["foo","bar"])
```

Return value:

```
"<select name=\"name\" id=\"name\"><option value=\"foo\">foo</option>\n<option value=\"bar\">bar</option></select>"
```

WTF is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the course of writing this question, I stumbled on its answer: Ruby has been lying to me (like it always does).

When you evaluate:

```
H.new.options_for_select ["foo","bar"]
```

Ruby tells you that the result was a String. But that's only because Pry and Irb both silently call `.to_s` on everything, and the thing that gets returned from `options_for_select` has a `to_s`. The truth:

```
(H.new.options_for_select ["foo","bar"]).class
=> ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer
ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer.new("<foo>")
=> "<foo>"
```

So whoever wrote these methods assumed that you want to incorporate raw, user-provided strings into your `<select>` tags, and those strings could contain attempts at HTML/JavaScript injection, so they must be escaped.

ActiveView treats all strings as suspect, but it is possible to mark certain strings as "safe" by wrapping them in an `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer`.